# Unable to upload video file with yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I tried to upload video file using kartik FileInput widget.
When I use the same to field to upload image it works very fine but problem arise once I turn to video.
This is activeForm field in my view file

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'myFile')->widget(FileInput::classname(),
            [
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'showUpload' => false,
                    'browseLabel' => 'Insert File',
                    'removeLabel' => '',
                    'mainClass' => 'input-group-md'
                ],
                'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*, video/*']
            ]) 
        ?>
```

And I use below code to save file in the disk

```
if(isset($model->myFile)){

            $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'myFile');
            if(!empty($file)){
                $path=Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/uploads/';  

                $filetmp = explode(".", $file->name);
                $extension = end($filetmp);
                $encryptName  = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$extension}";

                $file->saveAs($path.$encryptName);   
            }
        } else
        {
          throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, 'File not saved try again');
        }
```

When I upload form to the controller it return

> Unable to verify your data submission (400 bad request error)**

I have already tried to modify php.ini as

```
max_input_time = -1,
upload_max_filesize = 100M, 
post_max_size = 100M
```

And also when I when I tried to set `enableCsrfValidation = false;` in that controller action request post contain no data.

I don't know what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Used Yii debugger to find this info.

Comment: are you using the ajax upload as soon as you select the video or when you hit the submit button.

Comment: I submit together with other form field when I click submit button and post as multipart/form-data

Comment: please can you add your complete action code that you are using also the current Yii Version you are using

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadOmerAslam , I have realize where exactly is problem after moving project to web directory in Ubuntu, The problem was the update that I made in php.ini does not affect PHP built in server hence the changes in uploads properties does not affected, Now it function well in web directory. But still I cannot figure out how to updated the PHP built - in server to acquire the php.ini changes.

Comment: good to hear that